# Least amount of resources required in order to prevent deadlock?

Tags: deadlocks

Precedence graph of 6 processes and each number of resources they need to be fully executed is as follows:

| Process | Resource A | Resource B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 4 | 2 |
| P2 | 2 | 3 |
| P3 | 3 | 2 |
| P4 | 4 | 1 |
| P5 | 3 | 2 |
| P6 | 2 | 1 |

[image: Precedence Graph]

What is the least amount of each resource which prevents deadlocks?
The worst case scenario for resource A is when P4, P5, and P6 are running concurrently. which means we need at least 7 of resource A in order to prevent deadlock. The worst case scenario for resource B happens when P2 and P3 are running concurrently which means we need at least 4 resources of B. I know finding the least amount of resources independently will not always result in the correct answer in multi-resource situations, but in this case, it happens to be the answer and with A=7 and B=4, the system won't suffer any deadlocks. But my professor keeps insisting that in order to be sure that deadlocks don't happen when processes need more than one type of resource to be completed, the minimum amount of resources will be equal to the maximum of sum of all possible concurrent situations.
Isn't my answer correct for this specific question?